# How to give access execute specific php file in server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, octobercms

Hello guys first of all sorry for my bad english!. I'm having trouble with running a specific php file in server and I want to configure .htaccess to allow user to run the file.
example: www.mywebsite.com/theme/test.php

this is my .htaccess file and when I check my site it return "404 Not Found" `

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]


##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
 RewriteRule !^index.php index.php  [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`
Is there any way to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the rule labeled "Block all PHP files, except index" will route all requests for PHP files to the index file. Here are two ways to fix this.

## Simple, One-Off Solution

You can simply add this rule before any other `RewriteRule` lines:

```
RewriteRule ^theme/test\.php - [L,NC]
```

## More Flexible Solution

The idea below takes a different approach and works with your existing whitelisting rules. This might be better if you are goi to have multiple patterns or something more complex than a single file to worry about.

For your "white listed folders" rule, add the condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/theme/test\.php
```

So the block becomes

```
##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/theme/test\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

Otherwise, the rule labeled "Block all PHP files, except index" will route to the index file.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer ! i have another question about htaccess. I want when user enter "mysite.com/chat" , server interprets it to "mysite,com/theme/test.php" . Then what can i do ? Thank you again.

Comment: @ArefHoseinikia Glad to help! For your other need, you would want a rule like `RewriteRule ^chat theme/test\.php [L,NC]`. Also, in the future, you will probably want to ask additional questions like that by clicking "Ask Question." That way, more people will see it. :)

Comment: Thank You Again and Sry for my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Bro, maybe you can try with this:

`RewriteRule /Route/to/Your.php`

Your problem happens because you are denying all the files .php

Lucky with that.

Comment: Sorry buy what's your mean by /Route/to/Your.php ?

Comment: This is not correct at all, and that "rule" would not do anything because it's not a properly defined rule.